# how use tar and extract everything except certain files?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I want to extract website.tgz but I don't want these to "come out":

```
app/config.ini
log/
```

How do I do this?

Or/also how do I overwrite everything except the above?

Comment: from the manpage: `--exclude=PATTERN
           exclude files, given as a PATTERN`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try using the following command

```
tar -xvzf /path/to/tarfile --exclude='file dont want to extract'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I use `sudo tar xvf bds-ubuntu.tar --exclude=root/ -C mnt/` and I still see a bunch of junk at `root/.cabal` being extracted.

Comment: @Hi-Angel It does work, you just need to specify the full file-path or a wildcard. Since `--exclude` accepts a glob pattern, you could do `"--exclude=root/*"` (note that the directory will still be created, since the directory is it's own entry in the tar archive)

Answer (score 1):

You can use, as commented by [Gryphius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774116/gryphius), the `--exclude` option to [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/tar-invocation.html#SEC32).

You could also post-process the tar archive with [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/).

`tardy`  enables you to do other useful transformations (e.g. prefixing the archived file paths, changing user or group name, etc...).