# How to overwrite the structure of existing directory when using tar command to unarchive a directory?

Tags: tar

Suppse I got a file tree as following

```
workspace
├── project
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c (c is not included in project.tar)
└── project.tar
```

and`project.tar` was created by `tar -cf project.tar project-new` where `project-new` has following structure

```
project-new
├── a
└── b
```

So I was wondering if there exists any way that when I unarchive `project.tar` in `workspace`, I can completely overwrite the structure of directory `project`. In other words, after unarchiving, is it possiple to make sub-directory `c` disappear?

Comment: I don't get it. You mentioned in your first tree that the directory `c` doesn't exist in `project.tar`  and you would like to extract the files of `project.tar` in the directory named `project` without extracting `c`. Are you trying to extract all files but `c`?

Comment: @direprobs Yes extract all files except ```c```. I am doing this because I was trying to use tar to do a backup. Therefore, when I delete something from the original directory and backup again,  the deletion cannot be reflected by this way.

Comment: Have a look at this questions: [how use tar and extract everything except certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124742/how-use-tar-and-extract-everything-except-certain-files)

Comment: This might help: [Extract tar to a directory, removing any files it contains NOT present in the archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469924/74329)